# Getting a Dutch Passport

Tags: family, passport

Can I get a Dutch passport if my father was born in Holland and both grand parents were dutch?
I was born in New Zealand and my father immigrated here in the 1950's. My mother is Kiwi. Dad become a NZ citizen in the 1970's or 1980's.
I was born in 1962. If I am eligible how do I go about getting a passport?

Comment: If you were born in 1962 and your parents were married when you were born you were probably Dutch from birth, but you probably lost your Dutch nationality under some version of the ten year rule, either in the early 90s under the 1892 law or in the mid 90s under the 1985 law.  Ask at the Dutch consulate; if you submit the relevant documents they'll do the analysis for you.